# ILogger cannot be injected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ilogger

I have a .Net 7 core project which worked well concerning logging. However, I am having this problem now.

I have this controller:

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration? _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<AccountController>? _logger;

    public AccountController(IConfiguration? configuration, ILogger? logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = (ILogger<AccountController>?)logger;
    }
}
```

When I run the application, this exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate
> 'Modules.Authenticate.Core.Controllers.Api.AccountController'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method9(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Isn't ILogger service supposed to be added automatically? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the nongeneric interface and the weird cast? Request an `ILogger<ConsumingClass>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolve the closed generic `ILogger<>` (i.e. `ILogger<AccountController>`), injecting `ILogger` is not supported by framework provided libraries out of the box:

```cs
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration? _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;

    public AccountController(IConfiguration? configuration, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: And just like OP should do so before asking, you should search before answering. :)